# Conditional Text Rendering in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to render a `<Text/>` depending on a variable content, if the variable content was "kaveh" then render "Hello kaveh", else render "Hello world"

Comment: This not a way to ask a question, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your render method should looks like this:

```
render () {
   let s = 'kaveh';
   return (
        <Text>
             {s === 'kaveh' ? 'Hello kaveh' : 'Hello world'}
        </Text>
   );
}
```

this is based on your code.